# Como colocar una linea divisora en Listview

Tags: listview, flutter

Intento colocar una linea divisora entre cada item del `ListView` que se llena con los elementos de un **Array** quedando de la siguiente forma

```
body: ListView(
    children: litems
        .map((data) => ListTile(
              title: Text(data),
              trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                  onSelected: removeItemSelecteMenu,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  itemBuilder: (context) => [
                        PopupMenuItem(
                          value: data,
                          child: Text("Eliminar"),
                        )
                      ]),
            ))
        .toList(),
  ),
```

Yo intento hacerlo de la siugiente manera

```
body: ListView(
    children: litems
        .map((data) => ListTile.divideTiles(
          context: context,
              title: Text(data),
              trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                  onSelected: removeItemSelecteMenu,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  itemBuilder: (context) => [
                        PopupMenuItem(
                          value: data,
                          child: Text("Eliminar"),
                        )
                      ]),
            ))
        .toList(),
  ),
```

pero  me manda error en la siguientes lineas o codigo

```
children: litems

title:

trailing:
```

al pasar a revisar el error de `children: litems` me muestra lo siguiente

```
The argument type 'List<Iterable<Widget>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes revisar los parámetros que recibe el método `divideTiles` para entender como funciona, lo correctos sería hacerlo de esta forma:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: ListTile.divideTiles(
          color: Colors.black,
          tiles: litems
              .map((data) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(data),
                    trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                        onSelected: removeItemSelecteMenu,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        itemBuilder: (context) => [
                              PopupMenuItem(
                                value: data,
                                child: Text("Eliminar"),
                              )
                            ]),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
```

Otra opción que tienes es usar el [ListView.separated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html) , aquí tienes un ejemplo de como implementarlo :

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-adding-separator-in-listview-c501fe568c76